# List view control loses performance with large number of columns

Tags: c++, winapi, listview, wtl

I have a virtual listview control in report mode whose items I draw manually by handling NM_CUSTOMDRAW notification. The problem I have is that my performance drops proportionaly to the number of columns. By debugging the code I noticed that my OnCustomDraw and OnGetDispInfo is called for items that are not even visible in the client window.

If I have a list view with 1.000 rows and 100 columns of which only 10 rows and 5 columns are visible I noticed that OnCustomDraw and OnGetDispInfo will be called for each element in this 10 rows. Listview will send me notifications for all the 95 columns that are not visible.

Has anybody encountered a problem like this?

Comment: That's a ginormous number of rows and columns. Are you sure that all of that data actually needs to be displayed *at the same time*?

Comment: Actually, it can be even bigger. Number of rows can easily reach millions. Virtual grid can handle this with no problem on smaller number of columns. The problem is only when I start adding columns. It is not the end of the world, but it is noticeable and annoying to the users. List view control should not draw items that are not visible in client area.

Comment: Well, don't expect perf to improve when you add columns.  It needs to generate a message for each individual sub-item, message dispatching isn't exactly fast.  There are plenty of grid controls out there that can do a better job, albeit that WTL isn't exactly a popular vendor target.  No magic cure here.  No user enjoys digging through millions of rows of data, give her a break by offering a way to search/select a subset.  The perf improvements come for free.

Comment: The virtual mode of the listview virtualizes items. It does not virtualize columns.

Comment: The code you are using in LVN_GETDISPINFO handler is almost the only thing that influences redraw time.
Unfortunately you haven't provided any code so we can't see what is happening.
ListView will call your OnGetDispInfo not only for visible columns/rows, but also for others. It seems that it will often require all columns of one row.
However it works, your OnGetDispInfo must be super-optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ListView is implemented just the way it is. Just the following optimization has come to my mind:

Via control subclassing, track a list of visible columns. In the list view subclass proc, you probably need to handle the following messages (and maybe more if I forgot something):

- WM_CREATE
- WM_SIZE
- WM_HSCROLL
- WM_NOTIFY  (if ((NMHDR*)lParam)->hwndFrom is from the embedded header control; see docs for LVM_GETHEADER)

Whenever any of these messages comes, let the original proc to handle it, and then update the list of currently visible columns (see HDM_GETITEMRECT).

When handling NM_CUSTOMDRAW in the dialog/window procedure consult the list of visible columns and paint only if visible.

Comment: Hmmm, this would be a performance overkill. Virtual list view can request items many times in a second. Doing HDM_GETITEMRECT and calculating if column is visible or not each time is expensive.

Comment: "Tracking" does not necessarily mean "calculating each time". You may cache order of the columns and their left/right positions, and only compare that with horizontal viewport (given the corrent horizontal scrollbar position). You need to update such cache only when columns are reordered, resized, or when they are added/removed. And in those cases the header notificaitions tell you what column changes and how.

Answer (score 0):

I am certainly no expert on this but maybe you have to look at `LVN_ODCACHEHINT Notification Code` in the MSDN.